# 160KVA 3 phase UPS can take 222Amps load

Tags: ups

1. If I say that my 160KVA 3 phase UPS can take 222Amps load, does it mean per phase or total load?
2. If it is per phase, can I load 222Amps single phase load on each phase i.e a total load of 666Amps?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about electrical engineering not system administration.

Comment: I disagree with closing the question. As part of system administration roles which I have held in the past, I have been required to use an environmental monitoring system to monitor airflow, temperature, humidity, leak detection and UPS Systems. One of the things I would consider when adding new systems to server racks was how it would impact the phase loads - loading one phase heavily while not loading the other two can cause additional wear on a UPS system and increase electrical costs for an unbalanced 3 phase load.

Comment: @Evolutionise I agree. See my [this](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/8128/my-ideas-and-suggestions-to-the-well-going-massive-content-destruction) post.

Answer (score 2):

It means a total of 222 Amps (max load) over all 3 phases. So you should not use all of this on only one phase but share it over all 3 as even as possible.

Comment: Thanks Sebastain... but when we calculate %age of load(in amps) we consider 222A on each phase. ex. L1 - 78A    L2 - 80A   L3 - 78A. Percentage of Amps loading is shown as R - 35%    Y - 36%   B - 35% but as per your statement it should be R - 105%  Y - 108% & B - 105%.

Answer (score 2):

I will assume you are using 230V electricity and not 110V (US & some other countries) as the calculations do not add up if its 110V.

- P (Power) = V (Voltage) x I (Current)
- I = P/V
- I = 160000/230
- I = 695A
- I per phase is 695/3 = 231 
  Looking at Phase 2 which has an 80A load out of a max 231A, thats a 35% load (80/231 * 100)

These figures are not exact as there is likely to be some losses in the system which need to be incorporated into the calculations.